# website does not work on internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I have some simplified code that resembles the heading of the website I'm working on ([www.akkade.be](https://www.akkade.be)), everything works fine but internet explorer doesn't work well. How can I fix this?

The concept:

- I can set the height of #masthead the rest should follow (fit)
- inside #wp-custom-header there is the image, this should fit the
  whole #masthead
- ontop of that should come the .site-branding-text
- inside the .site-branding-text will come some text and or image

```
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      position: static;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }

    #masthead {
      position: relative;
      height: 90%;
      width: 90%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

    }

    #custom-header {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid green;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

    }

    .custom-header-media {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid blue;
      display: flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      background-color:rgba(35, 220, 160, 1);
    }

    #wp-custom-header {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid orange;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      opacity:0.4;
    }
    #wp-custom-header img{
      height: inherit;
      width: inherit;
    }
    .site-branding {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid black;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .site-branding .wrap {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid black;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .site-branding-text {
      position: relative;
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 5px solid black;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="masthead">
    <div id="custom-header" class="custom-header">
      <div class="custom-header-media">
        <div id="wp-custom-header" class="wp-custom-header">
            <img src="https://akkade.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-cropped-photo-1424894408462-1c89797f2305.jpg" alt="Compliance Excellence" srcset="https://akkade.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-cropped-photo-1424894408462-1c89797f2305.jpg 2000w, https://akkade.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-cropped-photo-1424894408462-1c89797f2305-300x180.jpg 300w, https://akkade.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-cropped-photo-1424894408462-1c89797f2305-768x461.jpg 768w, https://akkade.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cropped-cropped-photo-1424894408462-1c89797f2305-1024x614.jpg 1024w" sizes="100vw" width="2000" height="1200">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-branding">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="site-branding-text">
            <h1>hi</h1>
          </div><!-- .site-branding-text -->
        </div><!-- .wrap -->
      </div><!-- .site-branding -->
    </div><!-- .custom-header -->
    <div class="navigation-top">
      <div class="wrap">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        </nav>
        <!--.main-navigation-->
      </div>
      <!--.wrap-->
    </div>
    <!--.navigation-top-->
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer? Since you're using flexbox, refer to https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox for the compatibility chart.

Comment: internet explorer 11

Comment: @extreme4all IE 11 does not support flex properly, there are many known bugs

Comment: @RachelGallen so i should just accept my defeat?

Comment: You don't need to use flex, you can rewrite another way. Your decision about how to proceed is up to you regardless of my (or any) advice

Answer (score -3):

You are using CSS that Internet Explorer does not register. There is a way to add css just for internet explorer using an IF statement in CSS.

I think you should reference this article http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer as it provides good information on how you can design for internet explorer.

Here is an example on how to reference a stylesheet for a specific browser

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    /* css for IE 8 */
</style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Flex is not supported in Internet Explorer. 
Props to you for testing your website in all browsers though!

Comment: this is not an answer, if the resource you've linked will disappear for any reason the answer is completely valueless...

Comment: This answer is very much valid. I explained why his code is not working (Not supported in that browser) and provided him information about using IF statements in CSS. Someone could very easily find other resources for the IF statement if perhaps that link ever goes down.

Comment: no, it isn't... and it's been downvoted for that reason

Comment: what css is not working in internet Explorer and or what css should i add?